# new record in rails console error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

A very similar question was already asked, bud I can't solve the problem anyway. I am trying to create a new record in rails console and I get this error:

```
    2.1.2 :001 > subject = Subject.new
Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `subjects`
```

Can somebody please very specifically tell my what should I do?

Here's subject.rb:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

and schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140617074943) do

  create_table "admin_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name", limit: 25
    t.string   "last_name",  limit: 50
    t.string   "email",                 default: "", null: false
    t.string   "username",   limit: 25
    t.string   "password",   limit: 40
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "pages", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "permalink"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.boolean  "visible",    default: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "pages", ["permalink"], name: "index_pages_on_permalink", using: :btree
  add_index "pages", ["subject_id"], name: "index_pages_on_subject_id", using: :btree

  create_table "sections", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "page_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "position"
    t.boolean  "visible",      default: false
    t.string   "content_tipe"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "sections", ["page_id"], name: "index_sections_on_page_id", using: :btree

end
```

create_subjects.rb:

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string "name"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible" :default => false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
        drop_table :subjects
  end

end
```

Comment: We won't be able to do much until you post more code. Post your `subject.rb` and `schema.rb` files as a starting point.

Comment: log says `Table 'simple_cms_development.subjects' doesn't exist` have you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: I'm with gotva. It sounds to me like the table hasn't been created in your database yet.

Comment: Thanks. rake db:migrate doesn't help. I posted subject.rb and schema.rb in my question.

Comment: so your schema does not have table `subjects`. How you define model `Subject`, have you created migration for it?

Comment: I'm really new at this, but I think I have. I have posted some more code with migration in create_subjects.rb, I'm not sure if that is what you meant though.

Comment: Also you may need a comma in ` t.boolean "visible" :default => false` as in ` t.boolean "visible", :default => false`

Comment: After you do @MichaelDurrant's recommended change, you should then do `rake db:migrate` and all should be well.

Comment: There is still something wrong. Is it normal that there is no create_table "subjects" in my schema.rb file or should there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a comma in

```
t.boolean "visible" :default => false`
```

as in

```
t.boolean "visible", :default => false`
```

and then run `rake db:migrate`

Making sure that `config/database.yml` file has a valid entry for a database connection on your machine. Look at the `development` stanza.

More on migrations at [guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

More on configuring a database and the database.yml file at

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a subjects table that defines the attributes you want to persist in the Subject instances.

So say you want title and description. Use this command to create the migration:

```
rails generate migration subjects title:string description:text
```

And then run the command

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then try your Subject.new command

Alternatively, if you do not want to persist any subject attributes, change the subject class definition to:

```
class Subject

end
```